# Retrofit2 запрос с необязательными параметрами

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Сервер принимает POST запрос с таким телом:

```
{
   "user": {
      "abc": "asd",
      "bca": "dsa"
   }
}
```

abc и bca - не обязательные параметры. Как правильно сформировать этот тип для Java? Может надо передавать Map? Или для такого случая у ретрофита специальное решение есть?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете просто создать структуры `Request` и `User` таким образом:

```
class Request {
    User user;
}

class User {
    String abc;
    String bca;
}
```

Если строка будет `null`, то она просто не появится при парсинге (хотя смотря чем вы парсите) в Json.

В результате, при парсинге объекта `Request` с объектом `User`, у которого строки не заполнены, получится такой Json:

```
{
    "user": {
    }
}
```